# What components does OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX require for compilation?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, extents

I recompiled OpenLayers with minimal settings, and now Vector layer, that uses BBOX strategy, stopped adding bbox parameter to the queries.

What components do I need to add?

This is the current config:

```
[first]
[last]
[include]
OpenLayers/Map.js
OpenLayers/Kinetic.js
OpenLayers/Projection.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Vector.js
OpenLayers/Layer/OSM.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Bing.js
OpenLayers/Layer/WMS.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Google/v3.js
OpenLayers/Popup/FramedCloud.js
OpenLayers/Control/Navigation.js
OpenLayers/Control/Zoom.js
OpenLayers/Control/Attribution.js
OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/Panel.js
OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/SVG.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/VML.js
OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX.js
OpenLayers/StyleMap.js
OpenLayers/Rule.js
OpenLayers/Filter/Comparison.js
OpenLayers/Filter/Logical.js
[exclude]
```

This is quite important, because the complete OL is 990K, while the minimal is only 350K big, and my users may be in remote areas with very slow connections.

**It was not just Filter/Spatial**. I noticed that even with Spatial it didn't compose a query string. I bisected the whole list of components and it was... **OpenLayers/Format/QueryStringFilter.js**.

Comment: I added Filter/Spatial, and it worked. I also found out that Format/GeoJSON was necessary.

Comment: culebron: the OpenLayers build tools are really supposed to do this for you. This might indicate a bug in OpenLayers that it doesn't; you might consider reporting it as an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing the Filter/Spatial.js class, though it looks like it should be pulled in automatically by the BBOX Strategy without any work for you when you use the build tools. I would say that adding that should work -- and if it doesn't, I think that a simple set of OpenLayers code that demonstrated the problem with the build you're using would be helpful to attempt to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you look at BBOX.js in lib from openlayers dir you can see sth. like this:

```
/**
* @requires OpenLayers/Strategy.js
* @requires OpenLayers/Filter/Spatial.js
*/
```

when you add this two file to system, i think your problem will be solved.

i hope it helps you...